Single Variable change of variable and odd functions
If we look at an odd function the proofs I have seen to show that its integral is $0$ over some domain $[-T,T]$ relies on the following steps:
$$\int_{-T}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx$$
where we then use oddness of $f(x)$ to perform the following manipulation to the left hand term:
$$\int_{-T}^{0}f(x)dx=-\int_{-T}^{0}f(-x)dx=-\int_{0}^{T}f(u)du$$
where the last equality following from a u-sub change of variables (and changing the order of integration). However, I thought that in order to perform a u-substitution, we need to make the further assumption that $f$ has a continuous antiderivative. In fact most proofs I have seen to show the u-substitution method invoke the fundamental theorem of calculus:
if $f$ has continuous antiderivative $F$ then (assuming g is differentiable)
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)du=F(g(b))-F(g(a))$$
This leads to my question; intuitively it seems like the integral of any integrable odd function over some domain of the form $[-T,T]$ should vanish. Not just functions with a continuous antiderivative. So

Do all odd integrable functions vanish over symmetric domains?
If they don't is there a counterexample?
If they do is there a proof of u-sub that has more relaxed requirements?
I know that there is a method of of change of variables where the composite function needs to be a $C^{1}$-diffeomorphism. Obviously $x\mapsto -x$ is a $C^{1}$-diffeomorphism. Would this be a better way of going about showing that integrable odd functions vanish about symmetric domains?

